# symmetrical mesh does not react to symmertry in x-axis

Tags: modeling

I have a question regarding the Symmetry function in edit mode. When I mirror the teeth it looks like the picture I've included. It is fixable if I mirror around an empty object, but then the x-symmetry in edit mode doesnt respond and i can only edit one side at a time. I've already reset all transformations to deltas but now I am at wits end. Did anybody else encounter this situation and know how to fix it?[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe try a Mesh > Symmetrize in order to make sure that you have a symmetrical object, also apply the Rotation? Or please share your file

Comment: when I symmetrize it just jumps to the position like in the picture above, and rotation was applied [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=XyRs82oP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/XyRs82oP/)

Comment: You've played with the Delta Transforms, I don't know if you can reset the delta transforms without having to correct the location/rotation/scale afterwards...

Comment: thank you now i know whats wrong! oh ok thats a habit from maya, so in blender, should you apply the deltas at the very end?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, maybe tell me if this answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145857/how-do-i-apply-delta-transforms-to-normal-transform

Comment: jep I understand it a little better now, ty!

Answer (score 0):

You've played with the *Delta Transforms*, it has changed its location, rotation and scale, I don't know if you can apply the delta transforms, maybe check [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145857/how-do-i-apply-delta-transforms-to-normal-transform), if not you need to reset the values, then correct the mesh in *Edit* mode:

[image]